# netstat -a does not display all ports on red-hot

Tags: grep, port, redhat, netstat

I execute command netstat -a|grep 7777 and do not see port 7777, I try command with option -an and see it, I try with option -n and again don't see it. Please tell me why is this so? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the man pages for netstat:

```
-a, --all
   Show both listening and non-listening (for TCP this  means  established  connections)
   sockets.  With the --interfaces option, show interfaces that are not up

--numeric-ports
   shows  numerical  port  numbers  but  does  not affect the resolution of host or user
   names.
```

You will need to -n to show ip addresses as opposed to resolved DNS addresses and numbered ports as opposed to named ports. You will also need -a to show listening as well as established connections (which doesn't show without -a)